# Не получается создать в Android Studio новую директорию в папке res

Tags: android-studio, ресурсы

Не получается создать в Android Studio новую директорию в папке res.
Нажимаю создать директорию, она вроде как, создаётся, но нигде не отображается. Снова пробую создать в той же папке директорию с тем же именем, пишет, что директория уже существует. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что с этим делать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так происходит, потому что отображение проекта как `Android` группирует такие файлы 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В `Project` же показывает всё, как расположено на диске
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно использовать генератор ресурсов, чтобы не заморачиваться с созданием папок вручную
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выберите тип ресурса layout и имя файла, слева выберите `Size` и нажмите `>>` и там выберите размер, папка сама сгенерируется, если она отсутствует
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В отображении `Android` данный layout будет отображаться с квалификатором `large`, а при отображении `Project` он будет в папке `layout-large`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: Ещё вопрос, чисто из интереса, а я могу сделать так, чтобы папка layout-large была видна при отображении проекта как Android или это возможно только при строго определённых именах директорий?